# Using MCMC to calculate log likelihood

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, likelihood, numerical-integration

I have an analytical solution to finding $p(y|\beta)$ and $p(\beta)$. My goal is to find $\log p(y)$. However, the integral $\int p(y|\beta)p(\beta)\,d\beta$ is not analytical.

I did manage to use a Metropolis Hastings algorithm (using $p(y|\beta)$ and $p(\beta)$) to get a posterior sample from $p(\beta|y)$. Now I'm not sure if this posterior sample is supposed to even help me to get $\log(y)$ but if it does how?

I am basing this off the fact that you could get a lower bound on the log likelihood by using $$\log(y) > \frac{1}{N}\sum_{\beta\in\beta_s} p(y|\beta)p(\beta) $$ where $\beta_s$ is the sampled beta from the posterior. The above result is thanks to the EM algorithm where you set $q(\beta)=p(\beta|y)$.

Edit: Perhaps I might be looking at it all wrong, maybe some numerical integration technique will be better. This function is unimodal.

Comment: Notice that $f(x)=\int_\Theta f(x\mid \theta)\,\pi(\theta)\,d\theta=\mathrm{E}[f(x\mid\Theta)]$, in which $\Theta\sim\pi$. Hence, if you have and IID sample $\Theta_1,\dots,\Theta_N$ from the prior, then $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N f(x\mid\Theta_i)\to f(x)$ almost surely, when $N\to\infty$. This brute force simulation from the prior may be inneficient, specially if your prior is very difuse, but you should give it a try. Suggestion: use the standard error as an estimate of the Monte Carlo error.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately as you said the prior is too flat. I tried this without much luck. If it helps with the posterior simulations I can see where the $\beta$ is concentrated at.

Comment: It helps: use importance sampling with a distibution "compatible" with the posterior. Take a look: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration#Importance_sampling_algorithm